# javascript increment/decrement number with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, settimeout, increment

I'm trying to increment and decrement a number with a timer, my code doesn't work ...

```
var i = 0,
max = 5,
timer = function() {
    if (i<max) {
        i++;
        console.log(i) //ok
    } 

    if (i==max) {
        i--;
        console.log(i) //fail ...
    }

    setTimeout(timer, 60); 
}; 

timer();
```

Comment: It works for me (for a definition of work (since you didn't specify what you wanted it to do) of "Does not error and does what I expect that code to do").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When it gets to 5, the second if statement causes it to go to 4, then the first if statement puts it back to 5.

```
var i = 0,
max = 5,
dir = 0; // 0 for up, 1 for down.

timer = function() {
    if (dir == 0) {
        i++;
        console.log(i)
    }

    if (dir == 1) {
        i--;
        console.log(i)
    }

    if(i == 0) {
        dir = 0;
    } else if(i == max) {
        dir = 1;
    }
    setTimeout(timer, 60);
}

timer();
```

I use a direction variable to keep track of which way it's counting.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Rjf89/)

Comment: +1 A similar solution is to make `dir` the increment value by setting it to `1` or `-1`. Reduces the code a little. http://jsfiddle.net/Rjf89/1/

Comment: Thank you, i added a count variable to clear the timer (fiddle updated)

Answer (score 1):

@sachleens idea, a bit shorter code

```
var i = 0, max = 5, cnt = 1;
      timer = function() {
        i += cnt;
        if (i>=max) {cnt = -1;}
        if (i===0)  {cnt = 1;}
        console.log(i);
        setTimeout(timer,60);
      }
timer();
```